# Multiple Instances of Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I am currently facing a weird problem it is as follows.

Scenario-

I have two instance of tomcat 6.0 running on my machine

I am making a call from one instance to another via Service calls.

There are few system.out.println() calls on the 2nd server just to check whether the call was reached or not.

Problem - 
As soon as I have the 2nd instance running and there is a call from 1st instance I cannot see any output on the Tomcat Console.

tried changing swallowOut = true / false.

Nothing works does anyone knows what might the problem be.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any suspision messages in log files? Like incorrect port binding (tomcat typically use 3 ports for different connections. Each instance must have own unique ports.).

Comment: yes i changed all the three ports but no luck. as soon as i start the second instance the first one stops producing the stdout msgs on the console...